# Box shadow on focus

Tags: css

Why is the box-shadow on :focus not getting applied in this jsfiddle I have here?

http://jsfiddle.net/septerr/ZgZEY/

> :-|

Comment: What browser are you experiencing this in?  It works for me in Firefox 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out box-shadows do not work with select boxes and check boxes in chrome.

Answer (score 5):

Add     `-webkit-appearance: none;`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ZgZEY/1/)**.

As for the checkbox under a webkit browser, it appears to be a [known bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=92547) with the box-shadow.

Comment: Thanks. Setting {{-webkit-appearance: none;}} messes the select box and check box up somehow. Scrunches them up. It does show the shadow on the select box though.

Comment: Taking away the webkit appearance also takes away the tick in a checked checkbox, so you'll need to further customise this if you go this route.

Answer (score 1):

If you're testing in Firefox 3.5 or 3.6, and you're not seeing any box shadow, that's because you don't have a `-moz-box-shadow` prefix, which is required for [those versions](http://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow).

This should (and does) work as expected in other browsers that support the property or its WebKit prefix.

Comment: @septerr Might as well add -ms-box-shadow and -o-box-shadow too.

Comment: @post_erasmus: Those don't exist.

Comment: @post_erasmus: I respect PPK, but his site is full of tests for all kinds of prefixed properties that don't exist and have never existed. I don't use his tests anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you only need textfield or areas, you can specify a border. Somehow, if you give a border like `1px solid black` the shadow will work.

(I had a working shadow on textfields, so I added the different styles I had applied to it to your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZgZEY/30/)